# Android стек фрагментов

Tags: android, android-fragment, backstack, fragment-back-stack

Помогите решить проблему с стеком фрагментов.

В чем проблема:

Есть фрагменты - **A**, **B**, **С**

Я перехожу с фрагмента **A** -> **B**  с возможностью возврата назад (**addToBackStack**), при этом использую функцию **replace**

Дальше мне надо перейти с фрагмента **B**  ->  **C** без возможности возврата назад, использую функцию **replace**.

С фрагмента **C** пользователь не должен возвращаться по кнопке back, но при желании он может это сделать, если произведет пару действий на фрагменте и возврат должен идти на фрагмент **A**.  Я программно возвращаю пользователя с фрагмета - **C**  ->  **A** пропуская фрагмент **B**.

Если кратко то это так:

A -> B [replace, addToBackStack]
B -> C [replace]
C -> A [replace]

Все нормально, пока я не нажму на кнопку Back на телефоне когда я нахожусь в фрагменте **A** после перехода с **С**. Приложение выдает ошибку о нарушении в стеке.

Вот:

> 12-18 16:18:47.381 4116-4116/projectname E/InputEventSender: Exception
>   dispatching finished signal.
>
> 12-18 16:18:47.382 4116-4116/projectname
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback:
>   handleReceiveCallback
>
> 12-18 16:18:47.406 4116-4116/projectname
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already
>   added: fragment_logo{a9d527a #1 id=0x7f0e00b8 fragment_logo}
>
> 12-18 16:18:47.407 4116-4116/projectname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: projectname, PID: 4116
>                                                                                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added:
>   fragment_logo{a9d527a #1 id=0x7f0e00b8 fragment_logo}
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1319)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:916)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1666)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:586)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:169)
>                                                                                         at main.onBackPressed(main.java:656)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2483)
>                                                                                         at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2664)
>                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2736)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:224)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)

**UPD:**

Переходы:

**ФРАГМЕНТ [A] - ДОБАВЛЯЕТСЯ НА ФОРМУ ПРИ ЗАПСУКЕ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ**

```
public void ShowLoginFragment() {
        fragmentmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmenttransaction = fragmentmanager.beginTransaction();
        fragmenttransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.alpha, R.anim.alpha_end);
        fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.layout_main, fragment_logo, fragment_logo.TAG);
        fragmenttransaction.commit();
}
```

**ПЕРЕХОД НА ФРАГМЕНТ [B] - КОГДА НАЖИМАЕМ НА КНОПКУ.**

```
fragmentmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmenttransaction = fragmentmanager.beginTransaction();
fragmenttransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_to_right, R.anim.slide_right_to_left);
fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.layout_main, fragment_new_order_not_reg, fragment_new_order_not_reg.TAG)
                   .addToBackStack(fragment_new_order_not_reg.TAG);
fragmenttransaction.commit();
```

**ФРАГМЕНТ [С]**

```
fragmentmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmenttransaction = fragmentmanager.beginTransaction();
fragmenttransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.alpha, R.anim.slide_right_to_left);
fragment_new_order_status.callbackResume = callbackResume;
fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.layout_main, fragment_new_order_status, fragment_new_order_status.TAG);
fragmenttransaction.commit();
```

Так я передаю callback класс, к которому обращусь из фрагмента [C], чтобы перезапустить фрагмент [А] - **ShowLoginFragment()**

```
fragment_new_order_status.callbackResume = callbackResume;
```

Я пробовал делать все так же, но без

```
.addToBackStack(fragment_new_order_not_reg.TAG);
```

Все нормально отрабатывает после возврата на Фрагмент A, при нажатии на кнопку back на телефоне, приложение просто сворачивается. Но тогда у пользователя не будет возможности вернуться с фрагмента [B] а она нужна.

Comment: Пожалуй, если вы добавите код переходов по всем фрагментам, то вероятность того, что вам помогут, возрастёт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Разобрался**

**Во первых** - Если внутри фрагментов вы загружаете другие фрагменты то лучше использовать - **getChildFragmentManager()**

**Во вторых**

Добавил очистку стека перед загрузкой фрагмента который прерывает цепочку возврата.

```
private void clearStack(){
        int count = fragmentmanager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        while(count > 0){
            fragmentmanager.popBackStack();
            count--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Поправьте, что `getChildFragmentManager` можно вызывать только в API >= 17